# Limiting discharge current of super capacitor

Tags: power-supply, current, supercapacitor

I'm looking to use super capacitors to heat up a short length of NiChrome wire. My caps are capable of supplying far more current than needed to get the wire up to temperature (about 6 amps). What I need then is a constant current supply that'll operate over a wide input voltage so I can get as much power out of the capacitors as possible. Most solutions I've found, either implemented in discrete components or integrated as a feature in a load switch cut out near 1.5v or more.

This seems like a simple enough issue - am I missing a very obvious circuit?

Comment: How are you measuring temperature?

Comment: It sounds like a "cut out" near 1.5V won't work for you. Can you explain why not? What is the maximum voltage of your capacitor? What is the resistance of the wire when it is at the desired temperature (or, put another way, what is the voltage across the wire when it is passing 6 amperes)?

Comment: Resistance of the wire doesn't change much with temperature, which is why it's used in heating applications I suppose. My length of wire is ~80mohm so at 6a I'd have 400mv across the wire. My issue is that the capacitors only charge to 2.7v

Comment: While this is plausible approach, I see one major problem with using super capacitor here.  Unlike battery, the voltage drop begins immediately with discharge, so you won't be able to use all stored energy anyway. The only solution is to charge capacitor to much higher voltage than required for heating, which creates another problem - finding appropriately rated regulation element and getting voltage down to the supply required by whatever electronics you will be using to control it

Comment: _"My length of wire is ~80mohm so at 6a I'd have 400mv across the wire."_ - is AC current OK? What is the application?

Comment: You need to answer people's questions. || A buck converter will do what you want and can be relatively simple. DK Nguyen's cct can be modified. Instead of controlling temperature you sense voltage drop across a sense resistor (or even the main load, and PWM the supply voltage to maintain the desired current. Hysteresis allows current to vary slightly to allow on and off switching points.You need about the same components as DN's cct.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switching (for efficiency) constant current circuit, how about a circuit the supplies current when the wire is too cold and turns it off when too hot?

L1 slows the current rise and fall times to make the circuit more controllable if your thermal time constants are too fast. D1 protects M1 from L1's flyback voltage spike when current is interrupted through L1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJHw5a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I don't have a good way of measuring the temperature of the wire so instead I'm looking to limit the current supplied to it as that's very proportional to the temperature. A constant 6amp source at any voltage should be plenty.

Comment: @maxmclau You want efficiency in a constant current source which means a switching constant current source which means complex. Although the circuit above could be modified to use a current sense rewsistor instead of temperature which would result in a quasi-constant current.

Comment: I don't think temperature sensor is good idea due to complexity of making thermal contact and inherent sensor latency. In most designs with heated wire (e.g. vaping devices) the temperature is sensed via variable resistance of the heating element itself, no current sensing resistor necessary

Comment: @Maple Either way use of a current shunt in a simple thermostat circuit requires a way to deal with how interrupting current produces zero voltage across the shunt which causes the circuit to try to turn it back on again since it detects too low a current from its own interrupting action.

Comment: If you connect the diode across inductor and load you dissipate stored energy in the load (mostly) and have a buck converter.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Good point.

Answer (score 0):

A boost regulator could do the job. I say "could", since you are operating with such low voltages, and I don't know if there are devices on the market that will be suitable.
Also, remember that the energy in a capacitor is,
E = 1/2 × C × V**2, where the V**2 here means Voltage squared. And, if your voltage drops from 2.7 volts to 1.5 volts, you only have 30% of the power remaining in the capacitor. Maybe loosing 30% is acceptable, Only you know.
A solution might be to pulse width modulate the voltage, with the pulse width inversely proportional to the square of the capacitor voltage. (The square, since P = E**2/R, and I  believe I read that your heater wire stays at a fairly constant resistance.)
Also, placing super capacitors in series would give you higher voltage(s) to work with, simplifying your problem somewhat.
Finally, if you go the PWM route, be sure to pick a power FET with an on resistance in the range of very few milliohms.
ENJOY

Answer (score 0):

The question is maybe not so straightforward, but specs are: we have supercaps (if in series, parallel or a combination thereof not clear); we have the NiCr wire to heat up with 6A, but we do not know its resistance (it should be in the range of fraction of ohm to some ohm, for the mentioned 6A).

1. if resistance is very low (0.1 ohm or so) and the 6A are supplied into an almost short circuit we need a buck converter able to work in almost short-circuit condition, and with a very low input voltage if supercap is 1, or they are in parallel. Not advisable for a matter of efficiency.
2. if resistance is in the ohm range, then supercaps better to be series connected; and we choose an almost boost converter, as suggested by @tsunami-america (there is a grey zone with 5-6 V input and 5-6 V output, so we should choose a buck/boost without other details). Note: In order to avoid a custom design with controversial efficiency the supercaps should give 5-6V that is more or less the minimum sensible input voltage.

With more detailed specs better replies will come.